# manyToMany connection add existing entity or create a new one

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Imagine connection Person x Address (manyToMany). A user wants to add a person with the same address, that has a previous person.

```
 Person Address              Address                       
+------------------------+  +-------------------------------+
| person_id | address_id |  | id | postCode | city     |... |
+------------------------+  +-------------------------------+
| 1         | 1          |  | 1  | 15800    | New York |... |
| 2         | 1          |  | 2  | 25385    | London   |... |
+------------------------+  +-------------------------------+

 Person
+------------------+
| id | name  | ... |
+------------------+
| 1  | Jack  | ... |
| 2  | Peter | ... |
+------------------+
```

Is there some **automatic** way to:

1. Check if the same address already exists. If does add connection instead of create a duplicate address.
2. When Update Jack (from the example) and his address, add a new address instead of updating also address of Peter.
3. When delete check if there is an address connected with another person. If not delete an address, otherwise delete only connection.

In this case it's quite easy to check before changes are persisted to DB, but in more complex example it's really annoying when you have to check 3 records in the same moment that are all in addition connected.

Comment: My question is maybe stupid: Can Jack have many addresses?

Comment: Yes he can. That's why is many to many. I made it more clear with adding one table as person.

Comment: "Check if the same address already exists." When user enters a new address (each Key-up event), ajax call can be fired to run search for the same text in Address entity. That is just a matter of user interface, nothing much to do with entity associations.

Comment: You can do something like this but since you do not want both persons to be able to modify the same address, it will make more sense to just copy the address to a new one and connect that to the new user. It will make all further operations much easier

Comment: Djuro Mandinic when you have many to many connection and you want to store the same entry it's actually thing that possibly can be handle by Doctrine or isn't?